# Pyzmail syntax for for Python 3.6 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, doing some research I found out that adding pyzmail lib in py 3.6 will error out.

I found out that I need to install pyzmail. So I did.

That installed just fine.

Now, I am trying to figure out the syntax for decoding a raw message.

I tried:

```
message=pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(raw_message[1259])
print(message.get_subject())

ValueError: input must be a string a bytes, a file or a Message
```

I tried:

```
message=pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(raw_message[1259]["BODY[]"])
print(message.get_subject())

KeyError: 'BODY[]'
```

I found this:

http://www.magiksys.net/pyzmail/

```
msg=pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(payload)
print 'Subject: %r' % (msg.get_subject(), )
```

But, "payload" should be same as raw_message[1259], right?

What am I missing here?

Comment: How could anyone possibly tell you whether or not `payload` is the same as `raw_message[1259]` when you did not post the definition of either of those things?  `raw_message[1259]` appears to be a dictionary based on that KeyError you got, which is indeed not one of the types indicated as acceptable.  Is there some reason why you didn't *print that out* to see exactly what it is?

Comment: pyzmail does not support Python 3.6.  That's why [pyzmail36](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmail36/) exists.

Comment: 1259 is one of the messages from my Inbox@gmail. I retrieved it like this:
    raw_Message=im_obj.fetch(1259, ["BODY[]"])
    pprint.pprint(raw_Message)
I would put the output of the whole message here, but there is a lot of text.
The definition of the "payload" is mentioned in the url that I put in the original post. 
Another thing that caught my attention, once I install the pyzmail36 lib. When i import it, the autocomplete just has option for pyzmail (no 36). Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Analyzing what the message returned, I realized that the content was in bytes. That is the reason why it generates a keyerror.
I solved only by writing the string as: b "key"

```
message=pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(raw_message[1259][b"BODY[]"]) #it works for me
print(message.get_subject())
```